# Trying to show that the Neumann function solves the Neumann problem?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want to show that the solution to the Neumann problem

$$
 \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \Delta U = 0\quad &\mbox{in }\Omega,\\
 \frac{\partial U}{\partial \nu}\Big|_{\partial\Omega} = g\quad &\mbox{on
 }\partial \Omega,
 \end{array}
 \right.
 $$

is given by

$$
U(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} N(x,z)g(z)dS(z),
$$

where $N(x,z)$ is the Neumann function which is the solution to

$$
 \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 \Delta_{x} N(x,z)= - \delta_{z}\quad &\mbox{in }\Omega,\\
 \frac{\partial N}{\partial \nu_x}\Big|_{\partial\Omega} = - \frac{1}{\vert \partial \Omega \vert}\quad &\mbox{on
 }\partial \Omega.
 \end{array}
 \right.
 $$

The problem I'm having is showing that the boundary condition for $U$ is satisfied. Here is what I have:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial U(x)}{\partial \nu}\Big|_{\partial\Omega} & = \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}\int_{\partial \Omega} N(x,z)g(z)dS(z)\Big|_{\partial\Omega} \\ & =\int_{\partial \Omega}  \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}N(x,z)\Big|_{\partial\Omega}g(z)dS(z) \\
& = - \frac{1}{\vert \partial \Omega \vert}\int_{\partial \Omega} g(z)dS(z) \\
& = \dots
\end{array}
$$

I can't see how I can end up with $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \nu}\Big|_{\partial\Omega} = g$? In particular, I 'lose' the $x$ when I use the expression for the normal derivative of the Neumann function? Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can't you apply Stokes' theorem?

Comment: I don't see how that would help?